# python challenge, but for C++

Tags: c++

Does anyone know any site or book that presents problems like [python challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/), but for C++?

When I think python challenge, I do not mean only a set of problems to be solved with C++ (for that I could probably use the same problems of python challenge), but rather problems that will probably be best solved using C++ STL, special features of the language, etc.

For example, there is one python challenge that is specifically designed to teach you how to use `pickle`, a serializing library for python.

Until now, I only know programming contests problems, but they could also be solved with C, java or other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Code Jam](http://code.google.com/codejam) problems frequently have analyses with snippets of C++ code, probably because C++ is by far the most popular language used for solving code-jam problems. The latter also allows you to see many C++ constructs cleverly employed, as code-jam allows you to download the solutions by all the competitors. As most code is C++, you'll get to learn a lot of nice C++ tricks for efficient code.

Answer (score 4):

You might like to have a look at Herb Sutter's [Guru of the Week](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/index.htm) series of articles.

Answer (score 3):

There are many tasks on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page) that are [not implemented in C++](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Reports:Tasks_not_implemented_in_C%2B%2B) as yet. Try your hand at those, especially if you can use advanced features (templates, external libraries, etc.) to produce a particularly nice solution. Remember that there is no fundamental reason why *any* of those tasks should be beyond the C++ language, and there's usually several other implementations in other languages to show you other ways to attempt the task, which can help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a difficult time finding that because C++ provides less for you than almost any other language available. If C++ provides it, it's probably provided by Python or Java or C or any other programming language.

Why not try using some C++ concepts such as the STL to solve [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problems?